# Changing button to <a>

Tags: php

I have 2 questions. The first one is probably really easy but I don't know how to do it. I made a code that lets you save a music artist and a single and after you save it you can open it with a  but I want to open it with a button how do i do that.

And the second question is when you open the saved files I get 20 lines of things that are empty and 1 that is full (sorry for my bad english). How  do I change that into normal lines so it only makes a line if needed. Here are my 2 codes:

FILE NAME SEB2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <?php 

    if (!empty($_POST)) {           
                $artiest = $_POST["artiest"];   
                $single = $_POST["single"];
                    $fp = fopen("muziekcollectie.txt", "a+");
                    fputs($fp, $artiest."\r\n");
                    fputs($fp, $single."\r\n");
                    fclose($fp);
            }

    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="woorden" method="post">
        Artiest:<input type="text" name="artiest"><br>
        Single:<input type="text" name="single"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add"><br><br>
    <form>
        <a href="SEB2.php"><!-- <input type="submit" name="Watch" value="Watch" action="SEB2.php"> -->TEST</a>
</body>
</html>
```

FILE NAME SEB2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Het gastenboek lezen</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $bestandsnaam = "muziekcollectie.txt";
            // aantal regels per bijdrage om in te lezen
            // elke bijdrage bestaat uit 5 regels
            $aantal_regels = 2;
            // teller om bij te houden hoeveel regels
            // zijn gelezen
            $teller = 0;
            // Aantal bijdragen wordt bijgehouden.
            $aantal_bijdragen = 0;
            // gastenboek openen om te lezen
            if (file_exists($bestandsnaam)){
            $fp = fopen($bestandsnaam, "r");
            }
            else{
            echo "<h2>De muziekcollectie is nog leeg!</h2>
            <a href= 'SEB1.php'>
            Wees de eerste die erin schrijft!</a> ";
            exit;
            }
            while (!feof($fp)){
            $regel = fgets($fp);
            if (!feof($fp)){
            if ($teller % $aantal_regels == 0){
            // kop afdrukken
            $aantal_bijdragen++;
            // echo "<hr>";

            echo "<h3>Bijdrage: $aantal_bijdragen</h3>";

            }
            }
            // regel afdrukken
            echo "$regel <br>";
            // echo "<hr>";
            $teller++;

            }

            echo "<a href='SEB1.php'>Terug naar de
            homepage</a>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: for first question, you can either change the css of "a" tag to make it look like a button or you can use "<button onclick='window.location="SEB1.php"'>Terug naar de
            homepage</button>" . Second question is not clear to me, can u plz explain more.

Comment: show the output for the second question as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button link is not that hard

```
     <button onclick="window.location.href='SEB2.php';"></button>
```

I noticed you didn't close your form so that could be the problem when you tested it.

I'm not sure what you mean with the second part but I think it's just cause you do not have an if empty check on your post so empty input will be added to the file as well. If that's the problem this will solve it:

```
if (!empty($_POST['artiest']) && !empty($_POST['single']))
```